# jQuery CyclePluging next prev click event when keyboard press

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I show next prev pages when I click left or right keyboard arrow?

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ntrz/

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 39)
    {
        ???
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37)
    {
        ???
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use cycle('command'):

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39)
    {        
       $('#slideshow').cycle('next');
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37)
    {
        $('#slideshow').cycle('prev');
    }

});
```

Read more [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)